# Used: "git update-index --skip-worktree" on file. Now can't change branch

Tags: git

I added a file with git update-index --skip-worktree which works great. But now I can't change branch:

"Cannot complete the operation because of existing changes to the following file" and it shows the file that I updated the index on.

I had one commit where I changed that file. After that I realized I should have updated the index so I made the changes to the index and then reverted that commit. Then I made the changes again. Now I am in this situation...

Comment: You need to revert the flag to be able to switch `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` and surely stash the changes.

Comment: Why would I need to revert the flag? Settings the flag is what I want. So I have to set the flag again after switching?

Answer (score 2):

There are two flags that you can set for any file-name entry in the index: `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree`.  The flags have different intents—`assume-unchanged` is meant for extra-slow file systems while `skip-worktree` is meant for sparse checkout—but the two generally produce the same effect: the file remains in your index, but when Git goes to compare what's *in* the index with what's in the *work-tree*, Git generally just assumes that the file that is in the index matches the file that is, or maybe isn't, in the work-tree.

#### That's fine as far as it goes, but it doesn't help in some important cases

Remember that the index is perhaps best described as *where you build your next commit*.  As such, it contains a copy<sup>1</sup> of *every* file from the *current* commit.  As long as you're just making new commits *based on* the current commit, that copy can remain there undisturbed.  Your new commit, that you just made by running `git commit`, saves another copy (or rather, re-uses it—see footnote 1 again) of that file in the new commit.  The new commit *becomes* the current commit, and your index continues to hold the same copy of the same file.  No matter what you do to your *work-tree* copy of the file, the *index* copy continues to match the *current commit* copy.

But as soon as you reach for `git checkout` (or the new `git switch`) to switch *branches*, the picture changes.  Now you're going to select a *different* commit to be the current commit.  What if this other, *different* commit holds a *different copy* of that file?

In order to switch to this other commit on this other branch, Git is going to have to rip the existing copy of the file *out* of the index and, instead, copy in a *new* version of that file *to* the index.  That's OK to some extent, but when Git does that, Git will *also* overwrite your *work-tree* copy of the file.

We've already established that you have been changing the work-tree copy, without committing the changed file to new commits.  That's why you set the flag in the first place: so that the *new* commits you made would use the *old* copy in the index, not the *current* copy in the work-tree.  So the work-tree copy *doesn't* match the committed copies in each of the new commits you have made.

Git is now telling you that by switching commits, Git will **destroy** the copy you have in your work-tree.  You had better save that copy if you want to keep it!  You can save that copy any place you'd like.  Once you *have* saved that copy of that file—for instance, `cp path/to/file /tmp/save`—you can:

- remove the work-tree file, or
- use `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` to clear the flag, then use `git checkout -- path/to/file` or `git reset --hard` to overwrite the work-tree copy

so that `path/to/file` in your work-tree matches the copy of `path/to/file` in your index, or simply doesn't exist at all.  Now `git checkout <otherbranch>` can safely *replace* the index copy of `path/to/file` with the copy from the target commit, *and* fill in `path/to/file` in your work-tree with the copy from the target commit.  So now `git checkout` will be happy, and be able to switch to that commit.  And, if you want the work-tree copy that *was* going to be clobbered, well, you've saved it in `/tmp/save`, so there you have it.

Note that the difference between these two methods is whether the `assume-unchanged` flag is still set in the index copy of the file.  I prefer to *clear* the flag, because there's a tricky corner case.  What happens when the commit to which you want to switch—the one at the tip of *`otherbranch`*–*doesn't* have file `path/to/file` in it at all?  In this case, the `git checkout` operation will *remove* `path/to/file` from the index and from your work-tree.  Once the file no longer exists in the index, there is no way for Git to hold an `assume-unchanged` flag on it.  The file simply isn't there at all; you cannot set a flag bit on an entry that doesn't exist.

(If the target commit *does* have the file, and you want to set the flag again, you can simply set the flag again.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it contains a reference to the frozen, Git-ified data for the file.  This is shared with any other duplicate, so if the file really does match the current commit, there is no extra space used.  That is, thinking of it as a *copy* is subtly wrong—but unless you start using `git update-index` with blob hash IDs, thinking of it as a copy works out anyway.