# entry in .gitignore is not ignored, when repo is cloned

Tags: git, gitignore

There are dozens of questions regarding the problem, that files listed in .gitignore, but I haven't found a solution among these yet.

I have a repo with several config files. But these config-files are only examples. They should be cloned to local, but if changed locally not be written back. They should only be written to the repo, if I add them via `git add <filename>` instead of `git add *`.

So far this works locally, if I use `git update-index --skip-worktree <path-name>`. `git update-index --assume-unchanged [path]` should work as well, but I didn't try it yet. Once I do this, everything works as expected.

But when I clone the repo to a new machine and change this file, changes are tracked and written back, when using `git add *`. The expected behaviour would be, that the file is copied to local, but never written back as long as it is mentioned in the .gitignore file.

I'm sure, there is a correct way to do this and I'm doing it wrong, but how?

Comment: `git update-index` works _per repo_, it's not something that can be pushed/cloned/fetched.

Comment: @eftshift0 That's clear. I stop to track the file on the local repo, where it originated from. But why is it tracked after cloning, though in the .gitignore-list? Or how can I tell the main repo to not track it in clones? I could protect files, but this results problably in an error when trying to push.

Comment: `.gitignore` never actually causes any committed file to be ignored, ever. (It can't by design.) If you want a file to not be in a commit, don't put it in the commit. If you're building a new commit by starting from an existing commit, and the existing commit has the file, remember that you must explicitly *remove* the file. Don't put configuration files into Git either; see [this FAQ entry](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F).

Comment: But if I remove them (remove cached), they are removed in the remote repo also, which I don't want.

Comment: From this FAQ, I have to conclude, that it's not possible, as I want it to be. In my opinion a bug, not a feature.

Comment: What you can do is to have a template config file committed into Git, say `my-config.template`, which each user copies to the active config file name after cloning a repo. The active config file, since it won't be tracked, will be ignored by the `.gitignore` and changes to it will never be committed. When you want to take one specific change and recommend it to everyone, do it in the template too and commit that.

Comment: And that is in fact what is recommended in the Git FAQ: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files

Comment: I've written up [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70957498/3216427) to a related (but not duplicate IMO) question. Ignore the beginning of it, just pay attention to the section titled "The caveats, or why you should probably not do this".

Comment: Still not a fan. It's in my opinion not a good solution, just the least bad.

Answer (score 0):

Files that are tracked by Git are not affected by `.gitignore`.  Your question is a general case of the question, “How do I ignore changes to tracked files?” which is [answered in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) roughly as, “you can't”.  The FAQ goes on to say:

> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

The Git FAQ recommends using a template or example file that is tracked and filling it our or copying it into its intended destination, which is ignored and not tracked, using a script if necessary.